# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Tags: python, stellargraph

This is my code below and the error I have is beneath it but I cant figure out why this is happening.
Please share your thoughts

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

feature_size = 150
context_size= 2
min_word = 1
word_vec= word2vec.Word2Vec(tokenized, size=feature_size, \
                            window=context_size, min_count=min_word, \
                            iter=50, seed=42)



---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-59-dbe3a4fa3884> in <module>
      5 context_size= 2
      6 min_word = 1
----> 7 word_vec= word2vec.Word2Vec(tokenized, size=feature_size, \
      8                             window=context_size, min_count=min_word, \
      9                             iter=50, seed=42)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'
```

Comment: I think it should be `vector_size` https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec

Comment: Since the arguments for the class `word2vec.Word2Vec` are within the `(` and `)`, the`\\` is redundant.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, both helped me to debug the code. Thanks for being life savers :)

Answer (score 15):

I have met the same problem and solved it by looking up the [*Word2Vec embedding*](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Text8Corpus) documentation. Notice there are two changes in parameters in new Gensim:

```
[1] size -> vector_size
[2] iter -> epochs
```

Here is a code example from the documentation:

```
from gensim.test.utils import common_texts
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

model = Word2Vec(sentences=common_texts, vector_size=100, window=5, min_count=1, workers=4)
model.save("word2vec.model")
model = Word2Vec.load("word2vec.model")
model.train([["hello", "world"]], total_examples=1, epochs=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade to gensim version 3.8